# jQuery animate() with negative percentages Chrome/WebKit bug

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation, toggle

I am having trouble with getting an animation effect to work. It is being called inside a toggle() event. I am animating a div to a position of a negative percentage. This works fine when going from top:0 to top:-50%. However, when animating from top:-50% to top:0, I get a strange bug whereby the it automatically jumps to about 5% away from it's finishing destination and begins the animation from there.

I can only replicate it in WebKit-based browsers.

To view this bug in action, please see http://bni.mootexpress.com and click on the 'Find Us' link in the lower right of the page. It animates and reveals a map behind just fine, but when you click 'Find Us' again to close the map, you can see how the sliding boxes jump back to close to it's final destination before animating.

Comment: Shame, because that's a nice site.  Try setting the top position to -50% before starting the animate, despite the fact it is that already.

Comment: Thanks Archer, will give it a go and report back.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I tried using pixels instead of percentages and it works, but I need this site to be responsively built unfortunately.

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. The solution while trying to keep the site responsive is pretty nasty using jQuery alone. What worked for me was simply adjust the values with jQuery then rely on CSS transitions to provide the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an older ticket, but in case someone else runs into this issue, it may be that you're running into the bug with jQuery when you mix percentages and pixels.  Try changing your top:0 to top:"0%" or use pixels instead of percentages by converting percentages to pixels in jQuery before running the animate.

This looks to be fixed in later jQuery versions.
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9505